# How do I round to the nearest number between 0-1

Tags: c#

We need to round like this

```
0.15 => 0.5
0.5 => 0.5
1 => 1
152 => 1
1538 => 1
25000 => 1
```

How to achieve this ?
This is what i was trying

```
 decimal number = 10;
 decimal rounded = Math.Ceiling(number / 10000 * 20) / 20;
```

This don't work  as expected if number is 100000 or greater ,because give me 10 as the result

Comment: Why `0.15 => 0.5`? Why not `0.15 => 0.15`?

Answer (score 2):

Something like that:

```
public static Double Clamp(Double n) {
  return n > 1.0 ? 1.0 : n < 0 ? 0 : n;
}
```

However. in that case the 1st sample will be

```
 0.15 => 0.15
```

as the question states "...*to the nearest number between 0..1*".

**Edit**: an *extended* version of `Clamp` could be something like that:

```
public static Double Clamp(Double value, Double min, Double max) {
  //TODO: you may want to check here if min > max

  return value > max ? max : value < min ? min : value;
} 

public static Double Clamp(Double value) {
  return Clamp(value, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

if you're insisting on `0.15 => 0.5` it may be the case that you actually want

```
  Clamp(value, 0.5, 1.0); // [0.5..1], not [0..1]
```

Comment: The function is more commonly known as `clamp`.

Comment: If you call your function `clamp`, I would expect it to take in `min` and `max` values

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it should be 0.15 => 0.5, as Dmitry said. In that case, you can do this:

```
private double RoundIt(double value)
{
    if (value <= 0)
        return 0;
    if (value >= 1)
        return 1;
    return value;
}
```